# accessing gpio from within kivy android app

Tags: android, permissions, kivy, gpio

OK I am stumped and its possible I have just not had enough experience with android, so I dont know which [permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) to use.

**I have recompiled the android kernel** to expose the gpio pins I need, maybe I need to do something in the kernel to solve my problem... basically at this point i have no idea

I **can** open `adb shell` and go `/sys/class/gpio/export 141` and get the gpio folder and its files (value,direction,etc).

and when I am in the `adb shell` I **can** set the direction and values using `echo out>direction;echo 1>value;echo 0>value;` and everything works great , the pin drives low or high.

I put the `export 141` into `init.rc` and now that gets exported on startup.
If I try to access the value file from within my kivy app it crashes and says permissions denied (to be expected)

If I `chmod 0666` to both the `direction` and `value` it sucessfully updates the permissions in the file sys.

```
-rw-rw-rw- root     root         4096 2013-10-01 06:59 value
-rw-rw-rw- root     root         4096 2013-10-01 06:59 direction
```

now *when i try to write to the files from kivy(python) I get `[Errno 1] Operation not permitted`*  I get the same result if I try to `chown` the file to my apps user or to system.  I feel like Ive tried almost everything and cant seem to write to `/sys/class/gpio/gpio141/value` or direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I finally figured it out... right before I pulled out all my hair.

so for whatever reason it would crash and die when I would call

```
 with open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio141/value","w") as f:
     f.write("1")
```

however if I called it as

```
 os.system("echo 1>/sys/class/gpio/gpio141/value")
```

it worked fine.

Im still not sure why I would get operation not permitted when I would try to open it as a filehandle

Comment: `echo` automatically appends a newline at the end of the file, so maybe `f.write("1\n")` makes a difference.

Comment: I guess the cause is how Python do `with`. I'm pretty sure they try to `mmap()` file, which is of course no-go for virtual kernel file systems, e.g. **sysfs**. I suggest to file a bug against Python https://bugs.python.org/. @tshepang, I believe it has nothing to do with a new line.

Comment: Here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_io/fileio.c for `open()` the flags are `flags |= O_CREAT | O_TRUNC;`, here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273639/105842 @NominalAnimal opens it with `O_WRONLY`. That's probably what `>` in shell does. Definitely bug in Python, if the open flags are not accepted by kernel.